# Upgraded gitlab-runner from ubuntu-18 to 22, and now get this error in my job

Tags: 22.04, docker

I installed gitlab-runner on ubuntu-22 to test it out. One of the jobs consistently fails with

Step 2/4 : RUN yum install -y epel-release &&     yum install -y syslog-ng &&     clean_yum_cache
---> Running in ce3d895cd6d3
Service 'syslog' failed to build: cgroups: cgroup mountpoint does not exist: unknown

I did not have to do anything special on Ubuntu-18 to use cgroups. What am I missing in the install/setup of the Ubuntu-22 server? Is there some compat layer I need to configure because 22 uses cgroups2 be default?

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is to set cgroups to v1 in /etc/default/grub

append "systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false" to the command line.